# Rails 2 session clobbered some time AFTER variable is stored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dalli, session-store

I am working on an existing Rails 2 app.  I have converted a few of the hash data structures into objects, and if I put one in the session store, it seems to clobber the session, clearing out the user_id, among other things, and forcing another login.  I'm using dalli_store for the session.

The following code causes the session to be wiped out:

```
bug = MyClass.get_an_object()
session[:debug] = bug
```

It's not clear WHERE it is getting wiped out.  I can step through in the debugger to the end of rendering the view, and the session is fine, but when I hit another link in the UI, `session` is empty (Hash[0]), and I am redirected to the login page.

If I change the code slightly, to this, the session is OK:

```
bug = MyClass.get_an_object()
session[:debug] = Marshal::dump(bug)
```

However, if I store the actual object (even a deep copy), the session is lost.  I.e. even this does not work:

```
session[:debug] = Marshal::load( Marshal::dump(bug) )
```

bug.size is about 140K when marshalled, so it should not be overrunning memcached.  At any rate, I would assume that session is serialized by `Marshal::dump()`, so the size should be identical. It doesn't matter if I access the object in the session after storing it.  Just putting it into the session is enough to cause the problem, but as I said, the session is fine after storing the object, and all the way through the view rendering.  It isn't until the start of the next request that I find out that it has been clobbered.

I'm stumped.

Do you have any recommendations on how to debug this?  For the moment, I guess I can explicitly call Marshal to save the object, but I would really like to understand why the session is getting clobbered.

I know it's a Bad Thing to put big objects into the session, but fixing that part of the problem is out of scope for the current project ... maybe later.  Plus, I am very curious about what is going on here.

Comment: For a workaround, I explicitly called `Rails.cache` to cache the data object.  That works without having to manually call Marshal.  It does create the need to eager load any classes in the data structure to prevent a Marshal exception.  That seems messy to me, but not too difficult to get around.  This is a better solution than putting it into the session anyway (IMO), but I still want to know why it breaks.